# OpenID identity after "Test subscribe to app from Intuit App Center (OpenID)"?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm creating the flow in my application to sign up new users who come from the Intuit App Store. In a presentation (and other places in the documentation) it talks about getting OpenID information after the user completes the Try It process (simulated with Test subscribe to app from Intuit App Center (OpenID)).

When I do "Test subscribe to app from Intuit App Center (OpenID)" I don't get any OpenID info. And after going throught he Direct Connect javascript/oauth process I only get back OAuth credentials, no OpenID.

How are we suppossed to connect the OpenID to the account we create using the OAuth info gathered from the "Test subscribe to app from Intuit App Center (OpenID)" and Direct Connect process?

The IPP documentation for this part of the process needs major help.

Comment: Did you add a valid openID endpoint to your application? When that endpoint is accessed do you follow the discovery and sign in process?

Comment: @JarredKeneally yes, I have the OpenID URL: filled in the app setup on Intuit side. The flow is happening as it should:
->Test Link
->OAuth authorization pages on intuit side ->
hits my OpenID URL (but no OpenID data is passed in, hence problem)
->Use Direct Connect
->Returns to my oauth grant URL and gets a valid OAuth token
->Continue on to my signup page where I prefill info from some API calls.
Problem is I don't have the OpenID to connect the account I'm creating. So after account is created the user can't automatically login with SSO.

Comment: Are we suppossed to go through OpenID process before we call Direct Connect to get OAuth?

Comment: @Justin - Correct: OpenID first, auto-provision password-less account on your end if there's no email collision, and then DirectConnect.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, figured it out:

You need to do the whole OpenID process on the page that is hit from Intuit Sign In, Try It, or Test subscribe to app from Intuit App Center (OpenID) links.

From the documentation is sounds like OpenID info is passed to you from the process on the Intuit side before it hits your app. But this is not true. You have to go explicitly do OpenID after your app is hit.

Intuit: Please improve your documentation of this, it's not clear at all.